# Angular , ng-select problem , not displaying the selected value in the input area

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I use  component and  have a problem:

> The selected value not showing in the component.
>   And the style of control is strange.
>   My versions:
>
> "@angular/core": "^9.1.2"
>   "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0"

I take the standard example from 
https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-source
and the component in my project showing so:

[Before select:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjlBX.gif)

[After select:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgoy6.gif)

Comment: Hi, can you include your html code for the ng-select please
If the style is off it may be you have not included the theme as described here: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#step-3-include-a-theme

Comment: I added this line  @import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css" to my style.scss